# How do I get the value of UITextField text instance property and update UITableView row whenever the user edits the UITextField text property?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate, uitextinput

How would I update a table view row as as a text field text changes? It is difficult to create a string from the arguments in textField(*:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:) so that the string I create would be equal to the string value of the text property of the text field after the textField(*:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:) occurs. Is there a way to use the UITextInput protocol of UITextField? I haven't found anything on stack**overflow** about using the UITextInput protocol of UITextField except a question in 2012 using Objective-C that asks why he's getting a crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want something that calls a function every time the user edits the text field. You can do this by either connecting a function via the storyboard, or use a target in `viewDidLoad()`

Here's how I usually use it in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
textField.tag = 0 //Use this to differentiate between text fields if needed
```

And in my textFieldDidChange function:

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    String text = textField.text
    //Do something else
}
```

I hope I understood your question correctly. You can also connect an action from the storyboard for `editingChanged`, similar to how you would do it for a UIButton.

Comment: Ok. Very good. I didn't even think of doing either way. Thank you very much. I tend to forget things I've learned before when I haven't used them very often. I even forgot you could select which event triggers the '@IBAction'. I have gotten used to never even paying attention to which event is the default event when I create an '@IBOutlet' or '@IBAction'.